# How to write a SQL query for the issue mentioned in the description field

Tags: sql

I want to write a SQL that gives me the ouptut as following:

```
Elements    Elements/total  Elements/total2 Elements/total3
Books   6       
Books   Science 3   
Books   Arts    3   
Books   Science 1st Year    1
Books   Science 2nd Year    1
Books   Science 3rd Year    1
Books   Arts    1st Year    1
Books   Arts    2nd Year    1
Books   Arts    3rd Year    1
```

My Table Books_table :

```
Books   Stream  Year
Book1   Science 1
Book2   Science 2
Book3   Science 3
Book4   Arts    1
Book5   Arts    2
Book6   Arts    3
```

Please help me how to write the query.

Comment: Multiple UNION ALL., with GROUP BY.

Comment: which RDBMS are you using?

Comment: please give more details

Comment: Multiple UNION ALL., with GROUP BY. – jarlh 1 hour ago - can you please give an example.

Comment: which RDBMS are you using? – Yossi Vainshtein 36 mins ago - Oracle

Comment: Elements    Elements/total  Elements/total2 Elements/total3
Books           6       
Books           Science                  3   
Books           Arts                        3   
Books           Science                 1st Year           1
Books           Science                  2nd Year         1
Books           Science                  3rd Year         1
Books           Arts                        1st Year          1
Books          Arts                         2nd Year         1
Books          Arts                         3rd Year          1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want is Oracle's `GROUP BY ROLLUP` function.
It's an extension of `GROUP BY` which adds an extra row with sub-totals for each group. (check out the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14223/aggreg.htm)

`ROLLUP` puts the sub-total line immediately after the group, and you wanted it at the top of the query, so I added some ordering.

In my query, I also used `DECODE` to transfer year number into a readable format as you specified,

```
select Stream, DECODE(Year, 1, '1st year', 2, '2nd year', 3, '3rd year', null, null, Year || 'th year') as "Year_text", count(*) 
 from books
group by rollup(Stream, Year)
order by nvl2(year, '2', '1'),  Stream NULLS First, Year
```

Comment: Welcome. ROLLUP is what you were looking for.
you can accept/upvote the answer if it worked for you.